# button inside a movieclip that changes depending on the frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a dynamic map of France going from Roman times to 2014 and I have a problem.
Most of my interface is working except for one feature that requires a lot of mc inside the main movieclip. 
I can't post pictures so i'll try to explain what i did.

I have a main movieclip ("france_map"). Inside it, i have several layers including one called "rulers". In this layer, I have the timeline of every king/president of France. 
We'll focus on two of them: Sarkozy (frame 2007 to frame 2012) and Hollande (frame 2013 to frame 2014).
The mc "sarkozy" is only accessible between 2007 and 2012. On frame 2013, it disappears, replaced by the mc "hollande". 
When I click on one of them from root, a biography of the one concerned opens. 
It works thanks to that code:

```
france_map.sarkozy_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_sarkozy_btn);
function fl_sarkozy_btn(MouseEvent: Event): void {
sarkozy.visible = true;
close_fiches_btn.visible = true;
close_arbre_btn.visible = false;
sarkozy_txt.visible = true;
};

france_map.hollande_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_hollande_btn);
function fl_hollande_btn(MouseEvent: Event): void {
hollande.visible = true;
close_fiches_btn.visible = true;
close_arbre_btn.visible = false;
hollande_txt.visible = true;
};
```

But, I have two button I use to navigate the timeline (controlled by that code:

```
/* Avancer ou Reculer d'un an */

flecheg_sym.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_gotoprev);
function fl_gotoprev(MouseEvent: Event): void {
for each(var item: MovieClip in maps) {
    if (item.currentFrame > 0) {
        item.prevFrame();

    } else {
        item.nextFrame();

    }
  }


fleched_sym.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_gotonext);
function fl_gotonext(MouseEvent: Event): void {
for each(var item: MovieClip in maps) {
    if (item.currentFrame > 0) {
        item.nextFrame();
    } else {
        item.prevFrame();
    }
   }
}
```

When I use these button, all timelines move together. It works. 
My problem is that:
when I reach frame 2013 ("sarkozy" disappears, "hollande" appears), the new button ("hollande") doesn't work. And when I go back to 2012 ("hollande" disappears, "sarkozy" appears), "sarkozy" doesn't work anymore either. 
I don't understand the problem (i'm fairly new at as3 and flash). 
If i wasn't clea enough (english is not my first language), tell me, i'll try to explain more. 
Thanks for your help.
Jeryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And when I go back to 2012, "sarkozy" doesn't work anymore either

If you want to use MovieClip as a navigation instrument you should master it. When you go back from current keyframe that contains new assets and logic, and I assume previous frame isn't keyframe with listeners and logic, you will see graphics without any binded scripts. Briefly speaking, reassign your listeners for the buttons, use constant movieclip names, design your timeline appropriately and all be ok.

Comment: thank you. I will try this, and come back to tell if it works :)